# How to identify how many users are still having the app after installation on iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-developer, itunesconnect-analytics

1) Some users install the app and use it for some time and uninstall it.

2) Some users keep it but do not open for months.

How to differentiate and know the users count on such scenarios?

If users open the app, I can inform the server and know how many users are having the app. But If they uninstall the app or do not open the app at all for some months, is there a way to know how many users are still having the app after installation?

Is it possible to identify programmatically when the user is uninstalling the app?

I didn't see any option on iTunesConnect to identify how many users are still having the app after installation.

---

FYI,

For Android, PlayStore dashboard has the information on how many users still have the app on their devices.
The info icon on **Active / Total installs** says:

> Installs on Active Devices (devices online in the past 30 days with
>   this app installed) / Total User Installs (total number of unique
>   users who have ever installed this app on one or more of their
>   devices)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is not a simple metric available in iTunes Connect for this.  You would need to implement your own tracking with a combination of tracking launches of the app, as well as a "creative" use of the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) that will tell you when either a user has uninstalled the app, or has turned of notifications for your app.  Because you get the same response from APNS if the user uninstalls vs. disables notification, you'll have to be creative with combining that information with the app launch data. Even then, it will not be 100% accurate, but should get you in the ballpark.

More details can be found [here](https://medium.com/@puneet.sh25/uninstall-event-tracking-in-ios-62fdc6350360).